# SQL*Loader error on BOUNDFILLER field in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to parse line into columns in control file.

I get "Field in data file exceeds maximum length"

My control file:

```
OPTIONS (
ERRORS = 1,
DIRECT=TRUE,
LOAD=10
)
load data
APPEND
into table table_1
fields terminated by "#x000A"
(
Column0 BOUNDFILLER,
Column1 "SUBSTR(:Column0, 1, 10)"
)
```

Table:

```
create table table_1 (
Column0 VARCHAR2(2000)
Column1 VARCHAR2(124)
);
```

It looks like it happens because length of each row is more that 2000  but I checked the file and it's less that 1000.

So why I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error is here. `Column0 BOUNDFILLER,` this line is equal `Column0 BOUNDFILLER char(255),`.

`char(255)` is default value.

You are trying to put 1000 into variable with space only for 255.
Solution is `Column0 BOUNDFILLER char(2000) ,`